# does timestampMillis resulting from Play Integrity API check is timezone aware?

Tags: google-play-integrity-api

I'm implementing the "Play Integrity" API check.

In the integrity response there is `timestampMillis` that indicates when the request occurs.

Is it timezone aware?

Comment: I would expect it to be the amount of milliseconds since 1-1-1970 in UTC as that is the common usage, which should be easy to verify because [the example](https://developer.android.com/google/play/integrity/verdict#request-details-field) documents it as _"The timestamp in milliseconds when the request was made (computed on the server)"_. So make a request, and convert to a UTC timestamp/instant. If timezones were involved, I would not expect a milliseconds response, but instead a timestamp string which included offset and timezone information.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Are you sure? I get the response from an Italian server and timestampMillis was with timezone UTC+2, by converting it to datetime I got the Italian correct value.

Comment: If I knew for sure, I would have posted an answer. Given Google doesn't seem to provide explicit documentation of it, you'll need to contact their support.

Comment: This value is not timezone aware, as it represents a universal time reference. It is up to the client to convert this timestamp to their local timezone if needed.

Comment: @KareemAdel can you please explain more about it in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timestampMillis field in the response of the integrity API check is in Unix time format, which is the number of milliseconds since `January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC`

so ,it is not tied to any specific time zone but it represents fixed point in time that is the same regardless of the time zone when you parse timestamp on your end you can change to local time zone or any other time zone

example in js

```js
const unixTimestamp = 1681481133977;
const date = new Date(unixTimestamp);
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

[Unix time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)